# ArrayList and IndexOutOfBounds exception

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

So I'm getting an index out of bounds exception on some code i'm writing. What I don't understand is that I know for a fact that the index element I'm trying to work with exists.

Here's the code:

I have a constructor for an array list

```
    public StixBoard(int number)
{
    stixGame = new ArrayList<Integer>(number);

    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        stixGame.add(i);
    }

}
```

This block generates a random variable 1-3

```
public int computeMove()
{

    int numberOfStix = (int) (3.0 * Math.random()) + 1;

    return numberOfStix;
}
```

Really straight forward, now here I have a method that takes the parameter supplied and attempts to remove those number of elements from the array list. As you can see, the parameter must be between 1 and 3, and it must be less than or equal to the size of the array list. Otherwise, the user is prompted to enter another number

```
public boolean takeStix(int number)
{
    boolean logicVar = false;
    placeHolder = stixGame.size();

    if ((number >= 1 && number <= 3) && number <= placeHolder)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
        {
            stixGame.remove(i);
            logicVar = true;
        }
    } else if (number > 3 || number > placeHolder)
    {
        do
        {
            System.out
                    .println("Please enter a different number, less than or equal to three.");
            Scanner numberScan = new Scanner(System.in);
            number = numberScan.nextInt();
        } while (number > 3 || number > placeHolder);
    }

    return logicVar;
}
```

So as this program runs, the computeMove() method generates a random int (assuming the role of a computerized player) and attempts to translate that value to the number of indexes to be removed from the array list.

This ultimately brings me to this:

```
How many stix on the table? 4
|||||||||| 4 stix on the table
It's the computer's turn!
The computer chose 3

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2
at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(ArrayList.java:547)
at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:387)
at StixBoard.takeStix(StixBoard.java:38)
at StixGame.main(StixGame.java:55)
```

So as you can see, the array list is of size 4, but when the computer rolls a 3, (which should leave me with 1), I am left with this error. How does my array list go from being of size 4 indexes to size 2?

Comment: What you "know for a fact" isn't true if you're getting that exception ;) Use the debugger, step through your code.

Comment: oh doh. my else if statement is garbage. 

I ended up breaking the else if statement to TWO else if statements (number >= 3) and (number > placeHolder) and so far it seems to be working...will continue to test. Not sure how to close topics

Comment: Correct you are Brian, i thought I was seeing that code working properly but obviously i was not

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You iterate through your list, from beginning to end, and remove an element at each step. This makes all the elements in the list shift to the left.

First iteration: i = 0

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Second iteration: i = 1

```
[2, 3]
```

Third iteration: i = 2

```
[2] -> IndexOutOfBoudsException. There is no index 2 in this list.
```

Iterate from the end to the beginning instead. That willmake it correct, and faster since the list won't have to copy all the elements from right to left.

Comment: My guess is that the OP expected to use `boolean list.remove(Object)` to remove stick 1 to 3, but ended up using `Object list.remove(int)` which removes the item at the index given.

Comment: Ah geeze I feel silly now, i was under the assumption that since I had instantiated the array list of a defined value that it would generate null elements when using the .remove() method...if i actually even wanted that I should have just used an array. Thanks for the help, problem solved!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in this loop:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        stixGame.remove(i);
        logicVar = true;
    }
```

**Once you remove the elements then list size is also decreased.** If you start with list size 3 then in 3rd iteration, the index becomes `2 as initially 0 then 1 then 2` while size becomes `1 as intially 3 then 2 then 1`. Hence `IndexOutOfBoundException`.

Try this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++){
        stixGame.remove(0);//remove 0th index as previous element was removed
        logicVar = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at it this way.

When you start your for-loop the ArrayList is of size `x`.

When you call `remove()` you take an element from the list. So the size is `x-1`.

But if you're constantly increasing the element you're removing, eventually you'll be removing an index that no longer exists. Remember, when you call `remove()` the contents of the array list are shifted. So if you had 0,1,2,3 before and removed 2. The list is 0,1,3. if you call `remove(4)` which was valid initially, you'll get an Out Of Bounds exception